# Generic catch-all error template

Tags: error-templates

**Is there a catch all error page template?**

I'd like to use http://http.cat for my statuses.

*(originally asked by Bryan Redeagle in [Craft Slack](https://craftcms.slack.com/archives/general/p1458942743002729))*

Answer (score 5):

Yes — an `error.twig` template in your error templates directory serves as a catch-all template when a more specific template (e.g. `404.twig`) can't be found, or when the system throws a general error that doesn't have a status code attached.

(You can customize the path prefix for error templates by changing the `errorTemplatePrefix` setting in the [Craft General Config](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings).)

Comment: It should be noted that error templates do not work in dev mode.